# How do you edit an NSTextView in Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I am using Xcode to create a Cocoa application for Mac OS X. I have a lot of text that I want to put in an `NSTextView`. Unfortunately, I cannot edit the text in my `NSTextView` in Interface Builder; I can only edit it when the app launches.

Is there a simple way to edit the text of an `NSTextView` **before** the app launches (in Interface Builder)?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[yourView insertText:@"Your text here"];
```

If you want to do it in IB, change the title (I think that's what it's called) in the inspector pane.

Comment: I know I can do this, but the problem is I need multiple line (the enter key)

Comment: There is no title for a text view.

Comment: @MattS.: I have Xcode 4.2.1 and it does not show a “title” attribute for an NSTextView: http://i.imgur.com/X9nwF.png

Comment: I give myself the look of disapproval, I was looking at NSTextField (multiline) instead of a view ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I want to have a NSText thing in which you can scroll through text

Answer (score 1):

You used to be able to do this by double-clicking on the text view, and Xcode still shows the I-beam cursor when you do that, so I'd say it's a bug and you should [report it](https://bugreport.apple.com/).